# How to tell if my Lenovo T400 laptop is with or without IEEE 1394 models

Tags: bios, thinkpad

My laptop is Lenovo T400. Its ThinkVantage Toolbox notified me that I have to deal with [System Issues after Battery Drain](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-74161&selectarea=SUPPORT&tempselected=5&AID=10429688&PID=3719336&CJURL=http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do%3Flndocid%3DMIGR-74161%26selectarea%3DSUPPORT%26tempselected%3D5). The link asked me to update my BIOS and Embedded Controller code, for which I have to decide if my T400 is with or without IEEE 1394 models. Does anyone happen to know what IEEE 1394 models are and how to tell if my laptop is with or without them?

Comment: ThinkVantage System Update should always identify the correct BIOS for you, for the record.

Comment: Does it? I didn't see that coming. It just directed me to the IBM webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your system is one of the "IEEE 1394 models", it will simply have a Firewire port. On the T400, it is located on the front left, next to the wireless on/off switch:

[image]